# How do I start a site at a specific anchor without having all links lead to this anchor?

Tags: html, location, anchor

Let me explain: I have a site, `index.html` 
The site should start at a specific anchor, which is at the very bottom of the page. I did this using this code:

```
setTimeout("window.location.href='index.html#start'",0);
```

The problem is: I want to share a link to other people, e.g. `index.html/#work`
In this case, the site SHOULD NOT move to the `#start` anchor. But it does.

So here's my question: Is there a possibility that a site only scrolls to `#start` if the requested site is `index.html` and always remains like it is if the requested site has an anchor in it? (e.g. `index.html/#anchor`)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
if (window.location.hash === "") {
    window.location.hash = "start"
}
```

There's no reason to wrap the hash change in a `setTimeout`, and instead of changing the `href`, just change `hash`, so that it will still work if you change the name of the file or move the code to a different file.

Also, remember to wrap the code in a `window.onload`, so the element that you're trying to jump to actually exists. (use `window.onload = function() { /* code here */ }`)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sounded so good, I tried it, it works well for the other anchors and it also adds #start to index.html. but: the page does not scroll to the anchor. It only scrolls there after I refresh it again

Comment: @user2880389 Did you wrap the code in a `window.onload` (or `$(document).ready` in jQuery)?

Comment: no, I just put it in like this: <script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hash === "") {
    window.location.hash = "start",0
}
</script>

Comment: @user2880389 Well the page hasn't loaded when the code runs, so it can't jump to the element that's not there yet. You have to wrap it in an `onload`.

Comment: how exactly do you have to wrap it? I'm sorry, I'm new at this

Comment: thank you so much! it works! (it has a certain delay, but I guess that's because it has to load the whole page before jumping to the anchor)

Comment: @user2880389 Yes, the whole page must load before you can jump anywhere. If the answer worked, please accept it by clicking on the green checkmark on the left so the question is marked as resolved!